# Requet() with special character

Tags: javascript, node.js

why request() fails when I have this character `★`. I  need to do a request with that character but it always fails. Thank you

Comment: What's your code and in what way is it failing?

Comment: you should use `encodeURI` and `decodeURI`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather unclear. In the future, please take a look at the [Stack Overflow guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

That said, I'll take a shot at answering anyway. It seems like you want to use a non unicode character in a URL you pass to the Node request api.

Characters in URLs must be [Percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You could spend your time looking through the specification for URL encoding, but luckily for you, javascript has the handy function [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

You can use it like this:

```
request(encodeURI('http://www.example.com/api?character=★'), (err, res, body) => {
    // handle response here
});
```